# Alternative ways to applet with java web start

Tags: java, java-web-start, signed-applet

In my web application we are using java applet with java web start (jnlp) for showing ticket and printing from client machine using the selected data from web application. 
If the print is successful, then server gets related notification according to which we take further action.
Is there any alternative to it as I want to avoid installing jre in browser and different settings in the client machine?
Problem with the existing system is that if a client declines accepting certificate then we are not able to print ticket from the client's printer and we don't get any response.
If the user declines accepting the certificate then the server should get notified about it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Java != JavaSript`. Tag removed.

Answer (score 1):

> If the user declines accepting the certificate then the server should get notified about it.

Provide a parameter/propety in the JNLP file unique to the customer or that launch.  When the app. is set up and on-screen, have it 'phone home' to the server with the unique identifier.

Those clients that don't reply with the unique value either refused the certificate or had the app. crash fatally before appearing on-screen.

### The `property` element & `System.getProperty(String)`

#### JNLP `property` element

The JNLP `property` element is part of the [`resources` section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) of the JNLP file.

> The `property` element defines a system property that will be available through the `System.getProperty` and `System.setProperties` methods. It has two required attributes: `name` and `value`. For example:

```xml
<property name="key" value="overwritten"/>
```

> Properties set in the jnlp file will normally be set by Java Web Start after the VM is started but before the application is invoked.  ..

#### `System.getProperty`

See the docs for [`System.getProperty(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-).

> ```
> public static String getProperty(String key)
> ```
>
> Gets the system property indicated by the specified key.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll give it a try. Is there anything else beside applet which I can use to achieve the same result?

Comment: *"is there anything else beside applet which I can use to achieve the same result?"*  Sure, a free floating desktop app. (e.g. using a `JFrame`) also launched using JWS.  In fact, it's a lot easier than dealing with the applet/browsers/JRE interaction bugs that plague embedded applets. I often ask people [why applet at all?](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/)

Comment: But can I send data from web app to free floating desktop app for printing?

Comment: Can u please send some SSCCE for doing this (setting param/property) and using them?

Comment: An SSCCE (one single chunk of text to copy/paste) of this is not possible in that it involves both code and a JNLP file at the very least.  Also SO is not a code factory.  OTOH, see the above update for a start on the solution.

Comment: Now I am able to set and get property from jnlp file, but when I am trying to get property from dynamic jnlp (created using a servlet), I am getting null. I am setting property like this:<property name="jnlp.version" value="AppVersion111" />. Can u please tell me what I am doing wrong? I am using java6.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP output of the servlet using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: Try it again.  It worked for me just moments ago, and has worked for others in the past.

Comment: JNLP output is correct but I am not able to get the value (getting null).